# Jenkins Config File Provider replace token with latest tag/branch name

Tags: jenkins

I have a job to deploy a testing environment every time I tag `testing-XXXXX-rc#`

I would like to use the plugin Jenkins Config File Provider to have in my `.env` file a variable called `TESTING_TAG=XXXXXXX` where XXXXXXX would be replaced with `testing-XXXXX-rc#` or `XXXXX-rc#`, that way I can show inside the webapp which tag is the latest one used.

I assume I have to use the "Replace Tokens" checkbox

[image]

however the github README doesn't explain much.

Is what I want possible?